# Can simplexml_load_string be made to handle <br> tags?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got a case where I'm trying to parse a hunk of HTML that contains `<br>` tags -- that is, not `<br />`.  simplexml_load_string handles `<br />` correctly, but throws warnings (and fails to return a parse) with `<br>`:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 1 and div [warning]
simplexml_load_string(): <div class='dummy_root'><div>Basic text.<br> More text.</div></div>
```

I'm not the one putting the `<br>`'s into the text, so I have to find a way to deal with it.  I could of course write some sort of preprocessing / cleanup / text munghing code to replace the `<br>`s with `<br />`s, but I thought I'd check to see if there is something "better" to do here.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: `<br>` is HTML, not XML, XML needs to have the elements closed. Can you use domdocument? dom starting point https://3v4l.org/Av632

Comment: Or use simple html instead of simple xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is replace/remove the `<br>` tag like so:

```
simplexml_load_string(str_replace("<br>", "", $string));
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I went with, or something equivalent.  I kinda feel like expediency won out over a deeper and arguably better solution (like exploring htmlsimpledom), but this seems to be handling things fine.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Although the SimpleXML extension doesn't have an HTML parsing mode, the DOM extension does, and once parsed, they share the same internal code.

So you can parse the document like this:

1. Create a `DOMDocument` object.
2. Parse the document with [the `loadHTML` method](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).
3. "Import" the result into SimpleXML with the [`simplexml_import_dom`](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom) function. Note that this doesn't re-parse the document, it just re-wraps the internal representation in a different PHP object.

e.g.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$sxml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
```

The result is a SimpleXML object which you can use as normal.